# How to display RSS in Android?

Tags: android, rss

I'm using JSON in my app and I have a button "RSS", after clicking on which I want to see the RSS feed. While logging in, I also use JSON, but everything is done in background and the next view does not depend on JSON object. In LogCat I can see something like this `{"response":{"@attributes":{"count":"4","all_results_count":"4","page":"1"},"news":[{"content_id":"43366","date_added":"04-01-2010","content_title":"New News","content_data":"mika"},{"content_id":"111443","date_added":"04-11-2008","content_title"`..... But how can I actually display this on Android's screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSONTokener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) to parse the JSON string.

```
string json = getYourFeed() // some method to retrieve the json response.

JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
int count = JSONObject response = object.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("@attributes").getInt("count");
JSONArray array = object.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("news");
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    JSONObject newsItem = array.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.d("RSSReader", newsItem.getString("content_title");
}
```

use the get... methods of JSONObject to retrieve the rest the same way.

**Update, based on your comment**: I would start it simple, and then add more complexity as you get a feel for these controls. Create a String[] array with your news titles and add it to the list using an `ArrayList` adapter. It's very easy to use. Add an `OnItemClickListener` that shows a `Toast` with the full content.

Then, you can move to a `SimpleAdapter` version with a multiple columns `ListView` and perhaps a `TabActivity` that shows the full news.

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: And to display it I have to use the xml layout with, lets say TextView and with every "for" iteration just append an rss string?

Comment: @lomza you will probably want to read about [ListViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). See an example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Comment: OK, so in my jsonHelper class I created the method `public static News[] getNews(JSONObject object)` with more-less the same content you've written. And I use this [Screen Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), but I still don't know how to connect them. I have [NewsList](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1a25) (DataRequest is just a class, where JSON parsing thing happens). Now, when I press on News button, I get `Null Pointer Exception`, which is not odd actually...

Answer (score -1):

What code are you using to get those outputs?

I would parse it with something like a 'SAXParser' and Display it using an 'ListView'...

Comment: what's wrong with JSON output? And how would you use a SAX parser with this data?

Comment: I already use JSON Parsing and using something else won't be a good style I guess...